# ERROR: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: xml

Firstly I am very much a newbie with XML. I have written a VB.Net app to extract data from a database and output it to an XML file. When I validate the XML output using Notepad++ I get the following error:

> **ERROR: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.**

The initial section of the XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                   xmlns:lod="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeDRS_v1.2" 
                   xmlns:com="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/CommonTypes_v1.0" 
                   xmlns:xm="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
                   xmlns:lod1="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeApplication_v1.2">
      <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
          <lod:drsRequest>
            <lod:DeceasedDetails>
```

The relevant section from the XSD schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:tns="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeDRS_v1.3"
               xmlns:types="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/CommonTypes_v1.0"
               xmlns:app="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeApplication_v1.2"
               targetNamespace="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeDRS_v1.3" elementFormDefault="qualified"
               attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:import namespace="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/CommonTypes_v1.0" schemaLocation="CommonTypes.xsd"/>
        <xs:import namespace="http://bdm.vic.gov.au/Schemas/LodgeApplication_v1.2"
                   schemaLocation="LodgeApplication.xsd"/>
        <xs:element name="drsRequest" type="tns:drsRequest"/>
        <xs:complexType name="drsRequest">
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Where is soap in the schema?  The schema has tns,types,app while the xml has soap,lod,com,xm,lodi.

Comment: As I mentioned I am a newbie at XML, the schema was supplied by the vendor, so I have assumed that it was correct.

Comment: But how was the xml generated?  There is an inconsistency between the xml and the schema.

Comment: It is generated from vb.net code that I have generated. I understand that there is an inconsistency, but I do not understand what is actually wrong. Cheers

Comment: Then you have modify the VB so the namespaces match the schema.  The error indicates you are missing the envelope namespace in the VB code.